# SAS code to export xlsx file in Google Drive

Tags: sas

I have this dataset in SAS and I want it to be exported as an xlsx file on Google Drive. Is there a way to code/program this on SAS?

Thank you!

Comment: do you have the Google Drive app installed?

Comment: Just to add context: there are two possible questions here, one is "how do I export a file *directly* to google drive" and one is "how do I export a file that is then synced to google drive by the google drive app".  We need to find out which one you're asking.  One is much easier. :)

Comment: There is but Google requires you to have a developer token I believe making it a fairly complicated process whereas writing straight to a locally synced Drive app is quite trivial.